# Pycharm Jupyter server process failed to start illegal char :> at index 9

Tags: pycharm, jupyter

i'm using Pycharm2021.3.2 to run the notebook, the jupyter server is on another machine, i've checked the interpreter configuration and the firewall. When i click the run button, it give me the error.How can I fix it?

> "Jupyter server process failed to start illegal char :> at index 9"

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlUEU.png)

Comment: i have what seems to be the same issue. if you get an answer, please can you let me know. thanks!

Comment: I get the same error when using remote python interpretter (not sure Pycharm has support for that yet). No issue when running on local python interpretter

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error 'Jupyter server process failed to start illegal char :> at index 4'. I think diffrence of index number is originated by connection type. I used sftp. [My error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yisgx.png)

Your screenshot shows ssh. It looks like you are trying to run a jupyter notebook in a pycharm environment using a remote python interpreter.

The answer is, **after entering the 'jupyter notebook list' command, the output should be put as an input of the 'Configured Server'. not using 'Managed Server'**

I also had a similar error and I solved it. Here's a workaround:

1. Connect to the remote server where Jupyter is installed and run Jupyter Notebook.
2. Enter the 'jupyter notebook list' command on the server.
   This command shows the session information of the currently running Jupyter notebook. Here, you can find the protocol name ('http://', ​​caution! You must enter it!), IP address, and token information. If you use the remote access method by entering a password, you only need to enter the protocol name and IP address.
3. Enter the address from the above command in the jupyter server setting of PyCharm. Be sure to enter the protocol name, IP address, and token.
   [Detailed screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2ScK.png)
4. Done!

I have posted the solution process with pictures on my blog. Although it is in Korean, it was confirmed that the meaning was conveyed well when changed to Google Translate.
https://hoohaha.tistory.com/95?category=776277

If you haven't configured your Jupyter notebook remotely, you can follow the post below.
https://hoohaha.tistory.com/94?category=776277